# Display Twig Form with a loop

Tags: forms, loops, twig, symfony4

I'm currently working on a private social network for fun and to improve my skills.
Anyway, I want to display a form to leave a comment on a post using a loop but I have issues trying that.
I'm using Symfony, twig and bootstrap, and I'd like to keep js, jquery or ajax away.

Here is my code:

My form builder:

```
class CommentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', null, [
                "label" => "Your title"
            ])
            ->add('content', null, [
                "label" => "Your content"
            ])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
                "label" => "Publish your shitty comment!"
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Comment::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and my view:

```
<ul class="nav col-4 offset-3">
        {% for post in posts %}

            <li class="postItem">
                <article class="postItem">
                    <p> {{ post.title }} </p>
                    <img id="postPics" src="{{ asset('./pictures/posts/' ~ post.picture) }}">
                    {{ form(leaveCommentForm) }}
                    <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
                    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
                    <author>{{ post.user.username }}</author>
                    <div class="commentPost">
                        {% for comment in post.comments %}

                            <article>
                                <h6 style="font-weight: bold">{{ comment.title }} -
                                    By
                                    <author>{{ comment.user.username }}
                                        on {{ comment.dateCreated | date('Y-M-d') }}</author>
                                </h6>
                                <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
                            </article>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{ post.id }}" name="postId"> {{ post.id }}
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        Leave a comment
                    </button>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
                         aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Leave a comment</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    {{ form_start(leaveCommentForm) }}
                                    <input type="hidden" value="{{ post.id }}" name="postId"> {{ post.id }}
                                    {{ form_end(leaveCommentForm) }}
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                    </div><!-- /.modal -->
                </article>
            </li>


        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

As you can see I want to display my form on each iteration of post (with or without modal I don't really care I was just trying some things).

My problems here are:

*If I use a modal, I can't get my post.id inside my modal and so I can't send it to my controller.
Actually I get the value of first post.id for every posts.

*If I don't use a modal I can't even see my form on my page.

If you have a solution that would be great!

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: This line is wrong `<input type="hidden" value="{{ post.id }}" name="postId"> {{ post.id }}`

You need to get the value of the input field named `postId`and use it to build the corresponding leaveComment input

Comment: I actually get the value but it's the same post.id (the first) for every single post.

Comment: True, my bad...

Comment: No problem thanks anyway ;)